# Align <p> inline next to text

Tags: html, css, echo

I am trying to align a styled p tag next to some echo'ed text but once I add the display:inline; property the text does not align right.

Code:

```
echo $flight[0];
echo '<p style="display: inline; text-align: right;">'.$flight[11].' - '.$flight[13].'</p><br>';
```

Comment: You mind sharing HTML instead of PHP

Comment: If you want it inline then why use `<p>`?! Why not `<span>`?

Answer (score 1):

The text **does** align right. The issue is that *an inline element is only as wide as its content*, so aligning the text left, or center, or right, doesn't change anything visually. Check the example below. I've applied a border so you can see what's going on.

To provide a solution, please edit your question and clearly explain what your result is supposed to look like.

```css
p { border: 1px dotted red; }
```

```html
<p style="display: inline; text-align: left;">Text is aligned left</p>
<br />
<p style="display: inline; text-align: center;">Text is aligned center</p>
<br />
<p style="display: inline; text-align: right;">Text is aligned right</p>
```

Comment: The result will be identical, the only difference being that you *can* apply a `width`.

Comment: I thought it was clear that I am trying to "align a styled p tag next to some echo'ed text" in other words Im trying to echo some text and align more text to the right side beside it. How much clearer can I get